# How to set up a solid MySQL/MariaDB Server for +3000 active connections?

Tags: mysql, optimization, database-recommendation

**Background.**

I have an App connecting to an RDS instance on Amazon (r3.Large) and it's working smoothly. However, the boss does not like to spend ~ $1,000 bucks a month on it so we are moving In-house.

We are getting Dell servers with two physical Xeon processors and a ton of RAM, basically an r5.2XLarge r5.4XLarge RDS instance.

I'm no expert on Linux systems and I have installed MySQL through the XAMPP package from Apache friends before but I never get the same result twice. (I'm a newbie, please be kind).

**Considerations**

The server is going to be used primarily as a LAMP server, so other web-based apps will be using MySQL as well.
The App that uses the current RDS instance on amazon is a set of 3 executables for windows, each one of these executables uses its independent connection to the DB.

We have +500 PCs through 3 different locations but we are planning on expanding to +700 PC by next year.

We estimate we will be having around 5,000,000 to 5,500,000 queries by hour on a busy day.
And an average of 2,300 active connections to the DB.

A few times per day the Admin team runs heavy reports that are quite resource-intensive (the tasks take up to 40 sec to finish).

**Question**

Besides quitting my job and find a better one, do you have any recommendations on the configuration and/or installation of MySQL on the server?

**Edit**

Assuming I have MySQL installed...

Should I modify the "my.cnf" file to avoid having errors like "too many connections" or issues trying to import/export the old DB?

Thank you.

Comment: Sad story. Those $1000 bucks a month that your boss doesn't like to spend were buying him not just hardware, but also people who designed and maintained infrastructure, OS, and databases 24/7. Now it looks like you'll be doing it for free.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear your sad tale. What is your boss planning on doing when you have hardware & connectivity failures, or lack of administration experience eats all of your data? I sympathise

Comment: A bit mad all right. In 20 years, in-house databases will be considered like those who kept on generating their own electricity after Edison and Westinghouse became players in the power industry. Sounds like an interesting project which could be very good for your cv - even on Amazon, people who know how to install large apps on a Linux infrastructure (on-prem or cloud) will be in big demand as SREs and related. Give it your all, but don't be afraid of reminding the boss if it messes up that you can always go back to cloud! Best of luck and welcome to the forum!  8-)

Comment: To those about to quit: we salute you.